# how use Report Viewer in Visual Web Developer 2010 Express

Tags: reportviewer, visual-web-developer

i have created web site in Web Developer Express. Now i am going to add some reports to project. so i am using Report Viewer web control. You know that it is not in toolbox by default. i added it to tollbox and add it to form when i run it show report. but on design mode ut gives error **Failed To Create designer 'Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.ReportViewer, Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms, Version =9.0.0.0, culture=neutral, PublicKeyToke=....'**

Answer (score 1):

According to [this](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/632398/microsoft-report-viewer-add-on-for-visual-web-developer-2010-express-edition), the ReportViewer has been discontinued in Express, starting with 2010.

As a work-around, Microsoft recommends using BIDS 2008 (Business Intelligence Development Studio) for the report designer and the ReportViewer.exe redist for the run time.

Good luck!

Comment: O.k. Thanks. Lets say i will use Business Intelligence Development Studio for designing Reports. But next step i must add reportviewer webcontrol to form. And it will give me error. Failed To Create designer 'Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.ReportViewer'. But it work on run time

Comment: Ah, I assumed that the designer wouldn't work at all and that you'd have to add it programmatically, but I don't know for sure that's the case.  Sidenote: Shouldn't that version number be 10.0.0.0, if you're using the ReportViewer 2010 redist package?  Maybe (if the designer is supposed to work) a version discrepancy between the web.config/dlls is causing trouble?